# Query result not working with array type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables which contains a column with data type array in PostgreSQL. The structure is like below:

tbl_tour_packages

[image]

tbl_header_images

[image]

I have a query which contains several joins. The query is working fine with other joins and showing no error. But missing the values from tbl_header_images.
The query is:

```
SELECT 
    t1.tour_id AS pid,
    t1.tour_name AS title,
    t1.tour_duration AS nights,
    t1.tour_price_full AS price,
    t1.discount AS discount,
    t1.tour_seo_title AS seo,
    t3.category AS category,
    t4.image_names[1] AS image_url,
    CASE WHEN max(s.state_name) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE array_agg(s.state_name) END AS state,
    CASE WHEN max(o.destination) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE array_agg(o.destination) END AS destinations
FROM tbl_tour_packages t1
    LEFT JOIN tbl_countries t2 ON t1.tour_country_iso = t2.iso
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories t3 on t1.tour_category_id = t3.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_header_images t4 ON t1.tour_id = t4.package_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_states AS s ON (t1.tour_state @> array[s.state_code])
    LEFT JOIN tbl_destinations AS o ON (t1.tour_destination @> array[o.id])
WHERE t1.tour_status = 1
GROUP BY 1,7,8
ORDER BY view_count ASC LIMIT 6
```

I want to get the 'image_name' from tbl_header_images. Any quick help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps there's no data in image_names? It's nullable. The user might have not save any data in it yet, so it's null. Or if it's not null and there's an array in it, does it have at least one element?

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/

Answer (score 0):

before WHERE clause you should be able to do something like:

`, unnest(image_names) _image_names`

and then in select statement aggregate that back into an array

`array_agg(_image_names) AS image_names`

I don't quite get the `t4.image_names[1] AS image_url` attempt, but I'm sure you can pick it up from here.

so the whole query would be something like:

edit: I've stripped extra groupping

```
SELECT 
    t1.tour_id AS pid,
    t1.tour_name AS title,
    t1.tour_duration AS nights,
    t1.tour_price_full AS price,
    t1.discount AS discount,
    t1.tour_seo_title AS seo,
    t3.category AS category,
    (array_agg(_image_names))[1] AS image_url,
    CASE WHEN max(s.state_name) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE array_agg(s.state_name) END AS state,
    CASE WHEN max(o.destination) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE array_agg(o.destination) END AS destinations
FROM tbl_tour_packages t1
    LEFT JOIN tbl_countries t2 ON t1.tour_country_iso = t2.iso
    LEFT JOIN tbl_categories t3 on t1.tour_category_id = t3.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_header_images t4 ON t1.tour_id = t4.package_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_states AS s ON (t1.tour_state @> array[s.state_code])
    LEFT JOIN tbl_destinations AS o ON (t1.tour_destination @> array[o.id])
    , unnest(t4.image_names) AS _image_names
WHERE t1.tour_status = 1
GROUP BY 1,7
ORDER BY view_count ASC LIMIT 6
```

alternatively I'd go with subselect:

```
SELECT t1.*,
    (SELECT image_names[1] FROM tbl_header_images WHERE package_id = t1.tour_id) AS image_url
FROM t1, t2, t3
WHERE ...
```

Comment: This outputs no data at all.

Comment: Grouping on 8th was no longer necessary.